# requests.history returning empty output on Zapier

Tags: python, python-requests, zapier

Within a 'Code by Zapier'-zap I'm trying to check an url for redirection. But the requests-package doesn't seem to hand me a history.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.google.com', allow_redirects=True)
response.raise_for_status()

return [{'response':response.history}]
```

This code returns an empty outpout all the time. However Zapier says the `requests`-package is available on their service.

Anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Or is this simply not available on Zapier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Requests is indeed available in our python code step! So that part is working fine.

Per the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history), `response.history` only fills the array if any redirects happened. You picked an unfortunate example, as it turns out you can access google over http:

```
% curl http://www.google.com -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

If you access it without `www`, you see the redirect you're expecting:

```
% curl http://google.com -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
```

You can see this evident in the python code as well:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://google.com') # redirects by default
>>> response.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Hi @xavdid,

Thanks for the quick reply! You are right :-) I got the response to work. But still struggling in the final output of my code. Unfortunately, Zapier Code Editor only tells you there is an error but not which error or where.

Weird thing is that my code works locally. Could you help me out?
And how? I'm a paying Zapier user FYI

Comment: Sure, I can take a look! I understand the frustration with the error message -
 we send back as much as lambda gives us and sometimes that's not a lot. Can you link me to the zap you're having trouble with?

Comment: He @avdid, Thanks for the offer. Turns out it was in my constructed output. I figured that out, but the problem now is (i want to test a whole bunch of requests) that i run into a timeout. So i let al the requests be handled individually (downstream), but now i cant fin way to collect all the individual streams in the end (triggered by last) to send the result at once. Zapp# 25324061

Comment: Hey, glad you got that working! The situation you describe is a tough one, but possible if you're patient with setting up a zap network! Thinking it over a bit, I would make two zaps: Zap A parses the email and has code that calls a webhook to do the processing (zap B). Zap B does the time intensive stuff (in parallel) and stores there result in [Storage](https://zapier.com/help/storage/). Zap A has a delay step after the code, after which is collects all the values in storage and does something at the end. Make sure to clear storage in zap A when you're done!

Comment: Hi @avdid, I managed to get a lot further. Now i got a new but related problem. I've got an string (which contains a json outpout from a prvious step) as inputData. But JSON.parse doesnt seem to work in zapier. Is that correct?

Comment: That's not correct, the python and node js environments are standard and you can use anything available in the vanilla versions of each. Which language are you using?

Comment: Yeah your right. Turned out i dod something wrong going from a python output to a js input. Had to fix some formatting before i could json parse. Thanks for all your help. I finally got the zap perfect as i wanted it.

Comment: sweet! glad you got it working, that's always the best feeling. :D